# What is the approximation ratio of this randomized algorithm for finding matchings?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, approximation, randomized-algorithms

I would like to analyze the following algorithm in terms of its approximation ratio.

Here is the algorithm:

```
Input: A positive number T and two disjoint sets of nodes V={v1,...,vn} and W={w1,...,wn}.
Output: A matching S.
1: O = [] # An empty array.
2: for t = 1 to T do
3:     Create a set E of edges from V to W randomly
4:     A = LA(G) # G is the bipartite graph G=(V U W, E) and LA is
                 # an algorithm that takes as input a bipartite graph
                 # and outputs a matching A.
5:     O[t] = A # Put the matching A in the t-th element of O.
6: end for
7: S = max(O) # S is the maximum cardinality matching in O.
8: return S
```

In the algorithm above, called BA, there is a call to another algorithm LA, on line 4. We know that LA is a constant factor approximation algorithm for an NP-hard problem $\Pi$. An instance of $\Pi$ is a bipartite graph and we would like to return a maximum matching that respects some constraints. Therefore, LA will return a matching of size no less than a constant factor times the size of the optimal matching.

Note that BA is trying to solve another NP-hard problem $\Pi_1$ that has an instance of two sets and we would like to return a maximum matching between these two sets that respects the same constraints as for $\Pi$. The only difference between $\Pi$ and $\Pi_1$ is that $\Pi$ has as input a bipartite graph (nodes and edges) whereas $\Pi_1$ has as input a set of nodes only.

**I am not trying to hide the constraints. I still cannot write them explicitly in a readable way**. I will give some examples to clarify the problem.

- Say, for problem $\Pi$, we are given the following graph (it is represented by set of edges):

  `Instance of II = { {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 4} }`

  In this special instance, say, the optimal solution is

  `OPT of II = { {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {4, 4} }`

  Hence edge `{3, 1}` cannot exist in the solution because of the constraints.
  If we apply `LA` to this instance we could have selected, say

  `A = { {1, 3}, {2, 2} }`

  Therefore, the algorithm failed to select the edge `{4, 4}`.
- Now, for problem $\Pi_1$, we are given the following two sets:

  `Instance of II1 = (V = { 1, 2, 3, 4 } and W = { 1, 2, 3, 4 })`

  In this special instance, say, the optimal solution is (brute-force on all possible edges between V and W and apply the optimal algorithm for $\Pi$)

  `OPT of II1 = { {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 2} }`

  Hence, since we do not have the set of edges initially, the optimal solution for $\Pi_1$ is to select 4 edges unlike 3 edges for $\Pi$. In fact, it is clear that `|OPT of II| <= |OPT of II1|`.

  Now, at iteration `t=1`, if we apply `BA` to this instance we could get, say

  `formed edges in line 3 of BA = { {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 3} }`.

  Now we apply `LA` to this instance and we could obtain 
  `A = { {1, 2}, {4, 3} }`

  We continue until `t=T`, and then select the maximum cardinality set `A` obtained, which is `S` in line 7 of `BA`.

Knowing that LA is $O(1)$-approximation algorithm for $\Pi$, can I say that BA is an approximation algorithm for $\Pi_1$?

I think I can say that BA is something like $O(1+\frac{1}{T})$-approximation algorithm for $\Pi_1$ because as $T\to\infty$ and the 3rd line of BA is generated uniformly random, the solution produced by BA is no less than a constant factor times the optimal solution.

The pseudo-code is also given in more clearer way here:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your problem. From your definition it looks like $\Pi_1$ depends only on $n$, which is kind of weird. I suspect you're not telling us everything. Therefore I suggest you describe $\Pi$ and $\Pi_1$ explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Let me be more clear. On the one hand, $\Pi$ is the following problem: _given a bipartite graph, select a maximum matching that respects some constraints C_. On the other hand, $\Pi_1$ is the following problem: _given two disjoint sets of nodes, create a maximum matching that respects constraints C_. Hence, in an instance of $\Pi_1$, we do not know which edge to select. That's why in my algorithm I tried to create, randomly, some edges and then solve. I hope this is clear. If not, I will try to reformulate the whole question from the beginning when I get the chance.

Comment: No, I still don't understand. *Matching* for me makes sense only for graphs. Perhaps you should spell out the constraints and give some examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that the only feasible solution are single edges and $\{(1,1),(2,2),\ldots,(n,n)\}$. The optimal solution thus has value $n$. On the other hand, the optimal solution on a random bipartite graph is $1$ with probability $1-2^{-n}$. Thus algorithm BA would have to take $T=\Omega(2^n)$ in order to guarantee a constant approximation ratio, even though algorithm LA always outputs the optimal solution.

Comment: So, as $T$ goes large, BA produces a constant factor approximation solution. I cannot claim it is a $O(1+\frac{1}{T})$-approximation algorithm?

Comment: @det No, it appears your estimate is too optimistic in general. Convergence can be much slower.

Comment: Do you know of a way that let me derive the approximation ratio of BA? I mean what tools should I use?

Comment: There's nothing general. You have to analyze your particular situation.